# Algorithm for grouping related items

Tags: algorithm, grouping

I have a set of items. Each item in the set can be related to one or more other items. I would like to build an algorithm that group items that are related together, either directly or through other items.

**Example :**
My set is {a, b, c, d, e, f}

a and b are related. c is related to d and d is related to e.

The algorithm should produce the following groups :
{a, b}, {c, d, e}, {f}

Any ideas of an efficient algorithm for doing this ? Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: does `a` related to `b`, imply `b` related to `a`?

Comment: yes, it does. Maybe the word "relation" I used is inadequate ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [Union Find](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). It's incredibly fast. Using path compression, the complexity reduces to O(a(n)) where a(n) is the inverse of the the Ackermann function.

Comment: Amazing. Don't want to see the proof of this lower limit.

Comment: Well, I read Tarjan, immediately thought on _the_ Lengauer-Tarjan algorithm, and all the memory on those past compiler courses was flashing back :)

Comment: Thanks stOle for the answer ! I have used the algorithm as described in the Wikipedia article and it's working. Just one thing, the time spent seems to increase linearly depending on the number of nodes/links, like O(n). Maybe I missed something ?

Comment: I'll need more info on the implementation. :\ Can't really say. But I think it should be Linear, right? You have to go through each Item at least once. :\ Correct me if I'm wrong. Union Find will simply speed up the look up and merge. But you still have to go through all the nodes once.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on st0le's answer a bit...

So you have a list of elements:

a, b, c, d, e, f

And a list of relations:

a-b
c-d
d-e

Initialize by placing each element in its own group.

Then, iterate over your list of relations.

For each relation, *find* the group that each element is a member of, and then *unite* those groups.

So in this example:

```
1: init -> {a}, {b}, {c}, {d}, {e}, {f}  
2: a-b -> {a,b}, {c}, {d}, {e}, {f}  
3: c-d -> {a,b}, {c,d}, {e}, {f}
4: d-e -> {a,b}, {c,d,e}, {f}
```

You will obviously have to check all of your relationships. Depending on how you implement the 'find' part of this will impact how efficient your algorithm is. So really you want to know what is the quickest way to find an element in a set of groups of elements. A naive approach will do this in O(n). You can improve upon this by keeping a record of which group a given element is in. Then, of course, when you unite two groups, you will have to update your record. But this is still helpful because you can unite the smaller group into the larger group, which saves on how many records you need to update.