# How to identify groups/clusters in set of arcs/edges in SQL?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have arcs/edges like these ‘haves’:

```
Node1   Node2
A       B
B       C
D       E
```

Here A is connected to B and B to C. D is connected to E. In other words there are 2 groups/clusters shown in these ‘wants’:

```
Node1   Node2   Cluster
A       B       1
B       C       1
D       E       2
```

Could I use SQL to identify these groups/clusters? I guess this involves self-joins but I cannot see how to write this SQL. Any feedback would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The key is recursive CTEs.  The answer depends highly on whether or not you have cycles.

Comment: Have used recursive CTEs in the past in SQL Server. Thanks for reminding me about this possibility. Yes I will have cycles ... not sure what to do. BTW can you use recursive CTEs in TeraData?

Comment: Recursion in Teradata uses the same Standard SQL syntax as SQL Server (you just have to write `WITH RECURSIVE ...`. Is this similar to this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/40204509/2527905?

Comment: Ok thanks. I have notice that I can only have one CTE in TeraData. I used to break down my queries in several CTEs in SQL. Thanks.

Comment: No, you can have multiple (since TD14), but they skrewed it up (TD16 finally fixed this). You have to list nested CTEs in opposite order.

Comment: Whoa, they finally fixed the backwards CTE thing?  I wonder when we're upgrading...

Comment: Still interested in a solution/answer for this please.

Comment: Seems to be similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40204509/connected-components

Comment: @csetzkorn, can you kindly confirm the max depth of cluster?

Comment: @zarruq sorry I do not understand what you mean. Is this important for the recursion depth of the CTEs?

Comment: yes, we need to restrict the recursion (just like that standard one) at some point. If you are not sure about it, its okay.

Comment: Sorry I would not know this. Let us say 10 to start with?

Comment: @csetzkorn: Maybe create a fiddle and add some more rows to it.

Comment: @csetzkorn I think you want hierarchical data. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/hierarchical-data-sql-server

Comment: @csetzkorn did you check my answer ?

Comment: will do asap sorry

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45650663/905902 (and there will probably be more prior art)

Comment: seems impossible. did it expire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming from the sample data provided in question, that there is no loops like `A->B->C->A` in data, Following is the query that will return the desired output from `nodes` table.

```
WITH RECURSIVE NodeCluster (node1,node2,Cluster1) AS
      (SELECT node1,
              node2,
              Rank() Over (
                           ORDER BY node1)
       FROM nodes AS n1
       WHERE NOT EXISTS
           (SELECT *
            FROM nodes AS n2
            WHERE n1.node1 = n2.node2)
       UNION ALL SELECT N1.node1,
                        N1.node2,
                        NodeCluster.Cluster1
       FROM nodes n1,
            NodeCluster
       WHERE NodeCluster.node2=n1.node1 )
    SELECT *
    FROM NodeCluster
    ORDER BY Cluster1,
             node1,
             node2;
```

In seed query all the starting nodes are selected and `ranked` in `asc` to assign Cluster number to data in ascending order.

On the data provided in question, following is the output.

```
Node1 | Node2  | Cluster1
-------------------------
A       B        1
B       C        1
D       E        2
```

For re-assurance, more data has been added to the sample data as below.

```
Node1 | Node2
-------------
A        B   
B        C   
D        E   
E        F   
F        G   
H        I   
I        J   
J        K   
L        M
```

The query resulted in below output.

```
Node1 | Node2  | Cluster1
-------------------------
A       B         1
B       C         1
D       E         2
E       F         2
F       G         2
H       I         3
I       J         3
J       K         3
L       M         4
```

The solution query is successfully tested both with `Teradata SQL Assistant` and `bteq` in `teradata` and `ANSI` modes.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    DECLARE @Edges TABLE
    (
      ID INT ,
      Node1 CHAR(1) ,
      Node2 CHAR(1)
    );
INSERT  INTO @Edges
        ( Node1, Node2 )
VALUES  ( 'A', 'B' ),
        ( 'B', 'C' ),
        ( 'D', 'E' );
WITH    CTE_Nodes
          AS ( SELECT   Node1 AS Node
               FROM     @Edges
               UNION
               SELECT   Node2 AS Node
               FROM     @Edges
             ),
        CTE_Pairs
          AS ( SELECT   Node1 ,
                        Node2
               FROM     @Edges
               WHERE    Node1 <> Node2
               UNION
               SELECT   Node2 AS Node1 ,
                        Node1 AS Node2
               FROM     @Edges
               WHERE    Node1 <> Node2
             ),
        CTE_Recursive
          AS ( SELECT   CAST(CTE_Nodes.Node AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS AnchorNode ,
                        Node1 ,
                        Node2 ,
                        CAST(',' + Node1 + ',' + Node2 + ',' AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS NodePath ,
                        1 AS Lvl
               FROM     CTE_Pairs
                        INNER JOIN CTE_Nodes ON CTE_Nodes.Node = CTE_Pairs.Node1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   CTE_Recursive.AnchorNode ,
                        CTE_Pairs.Node1 ,
                        CTE_Pairs.Node2 ,
                        CAST(CTE_Recursive.NodePath + CTE_Pairs.Node2 + ',' AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS NodePath ,
                        CTE_Recursive.Lvl + 1 AS Lvl
               FROM     CTE_Pairs
                        INNER JOIN CTE_Recursive ON CTE_Recursive.Node2 = CTE_Pairs.Node1
               WHERE    CTE_Recursive.NodePath NOT LIKE CAST('%,'
                        + CTE_Pairs.Node2 + ',%' AS VARCHAR(8000))
             ),
        CTE_RecursionResult
          AS ( SELECT   AnchorNode ,
                        Node1 ,
                        Node2
               FROM     CTE_Recursive
             ),
        CTE_CleanResult
          AS ( SELECT   AnchorNode ,
                        Node1 AS Node
               FROM     CTE_RecursionResult
               UNION
               SELECT   AnchorNode ,
                        Node2 AS Node
               FROM     CTE_RecursionResult
             )
    SELECT  Edges.Node1 ,
            Edges.Node2 ,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY CASE WHEN CA_Data.XML_Value IS NULL
                                              THEN Edges.Node1
                                              ELSE CA_Data.XML_Value
                                         END ) AS Cluster
    FROM    @Edges Edges
            CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    CTE_CleanResult.Node + ','
                          FROM      CTE_CleanResult
                          WHERE     CTE_CleanResult.AnchorNode = Edges.Node1
                          ORDER BY  CTE_CleanResult.Node
                        FOR
                          XML PATH('') ,
                              TYPE
                        ) AS CA_XML ( XML_Value )
            CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    CA_XML.XML_Value.value('.',
                                                           'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                        ) AS CA_Data ( XML_Value );
```

[**SQL Fiddle DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/327da/1/0)

Comment: This is a way more complicated answer than zarruq's and based on SQL Server, thus doesn't work in Teradata due to `cross apply`.