# Replacing duplicate ids in Teradata

Tags: teradata

I have below table, with two columns in Teradata:

```
ID1      ID2
10        12
10        13
13        15
15        17
19        21
21        23
```

In 1st row there are 2 ids , 10 and 12. This means 12 is duplicate of 10, so 12 must be replaced by 10. Similarly in next row 13 must be replaced by 10. However in third row, there is 13 and 15, which means 15 should be replaced by 13. But, since 13 has been already replaced by 10, both 13 and 15 must be replaced by 10.

Output which I expect is:

```
id    orgl id 
10     10
12     10
13     10
15     10
17     10
19     19
21     19
23     19
```

Can anyone please help me out with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A single update can't possibly do this, because you need to generate new records to get to your expected output (regardless of what the actual logic is).

Comment: It's impossible to know what you want without knowing the logic behind, why *must* some value be replaced by another?

Comment: I am trying to match individuals, based on attributes. for eg: 

There might be an individual named 'xxx' who matches to another individual named 'yyy' because there emails were same and are given an id 10.
Similarly, 'yyy' can also match to another person 'zzz' because there phones were same and were given an id 12.
Also 'zzz' matched to 'aaa' because they shared same email and were given id 15.

Ideally they are all same person, so at the end I want to map all ids 10,12 and 15 to 10 and assign it to xxx,yyy,zzz and aaa.

Comment: @dnoeth Please refer above comment for the logic

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40204509/connected-components